# Run c shell skripts within shell skript and wait until jobs are completed

Tags: batch-file, call, jobs, csh

I want to call several C shell scripts within one master script one after another.
Since a previous batch script creates files which the following script needs, I have to wait until the first script has successfully terminated.
How do I implement the query whether the previous script is still running or has already stopped?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out:

```
 #!/bin/csh


 csh 1_script.sh
 set pid1=$!
 csh 2_script.sh
 set pid2=$!

 wait $pid1
 wait $pid2
```

Comment: you don't need any your references to `$pidN`. .... `$!` is the PID of the last process run in the background with the `&` appended on the cmd-line. Given your need to only have 2_script.sh run when 1_script.sh is done, running in the background would NOT be what you want. basically, you need a 3 line script, line1 plus the 2 calls to csh (you probably don't need csh either, just use ./1_script.sh or /path/to/1_script.sh etc. Good luck.